# Unable to get the backup log file when using RotatingFileHandler from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Brief :

**base.py:**

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os

slogFile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'LOGS', 'App_Debug.log')
if True != os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'LOGS')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'LOGS'))
logging.basicConfig(filename=slogFile, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("myApp")   
fmt = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
size=1024*1024*1 #1mb file size
logger = logging.getLogger("myApp")   
fmt = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

hdlr = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename = slogFile ,mode='w', maxBytes=size, backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=0)
hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)</em>
```

**app_main1.py:**

```
import base

base.logger.debug('xxx')
```

**app_main2.py:**

```
import base

base.logger.debug('xxx')
```

NOTE : for my application i am using another module that also recording the logs into the same file .

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 78, in emit

   self.doRollover()

 File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 141, in doRollover

  os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Logged from file `app_main1.py`, line 59

Could you explain this to me?

I want do backup the log file when its reaches the max(1mb) size.

Comment: What is your question? About your error or backup the log file ?

Comment: about the backup log file

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm getting a similar error in my app.

Comment: the issue still i am facing , have you resolved it..?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the log file open in some other program, which is why it can't be renamed. This could be one of your programs, or an anti-virus or full-text indexer operating on disk files.

Comment: yes the same log file is used by the another module , in this situation how can i take the backup log file,this file is to recorded based on the flow,my app interact with the another module to complete the task

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while developing a flask application. To solve the problem, I had to change the environmental variable from 
`"FLASK_DEBUG=1"` to `"FLASK_DEBUG=0"`. The reason being that turning debugging on leads to threading errors. I got the solution after reading [this blog](http://azaleasays.com/2014/05/01/django-logging-with-rotatingfilehandler-error/)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since you imported base.py twice, the RotatingFileHandler is setup twice, therefore it is accessed by two processes.

I had a similar problem today due to this reason. Details [here](http://azaleasays.com/2014/05/01/django-logging-with-rotatingfilehandler-error/).

I would suggest not importing base.py, but creating a child logger in app_main1.py and app_main2.py. You can refer to the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules).